# how can I add a path permanently

Tags: unix, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Every time I open my secureCRT window,I need to run the below to export the path..is there a way to add this permanently to the PATH?

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Yes there is, but it depends on the shell you are using. E.g. for `csh` it might be set in `.cshrc`, for `bash` in `.bashrc', or just in `.profile`.  Can you add which shell you use to the post?

Comment: @ Hennes - am using bash

Answer (score 0):

When you log in and start bash as a login shell (bash -l) these scripts will be read:

System wide:

- /etc/profile
  (This one should be shell independent, since it may also be called from ksh, sh, etc etc).
- /etc/bashrc/

Personal:

- ~/.profile
- ~/.bash_profile (this one might actually source the .bashrc file)
- ~/.bashrc

Decide if you want to make system wide, or user only changes. Then look for these files and select one of them. Add the path changes and start a new shell. Test. If it does not work, close the shell (with logout or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>) and correct the typo.

Note that I did not write 'log out and start a new shell'.

Comment: Bash (at least when invoked interactively) looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and only sources the first when found, skipping the others. ~/.bashrc is only called for non-interactive startup (but for terminals on most *nix systems). See also: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html